# iOS use Photolibrary API, how can I get album photos named"from my mac"( which is transform from my mac)

Tags: ios, photo

i transform some pictures from my mac to iphone through itunes,
then there have on collection named "from my mac" in my iPhone。
i want show those pictures in my own application(code by Object-C).
how can i get those photos, have some api for this?

Answer (score 0):

[PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny options:nil];

finally i find all in the lib header.h

1. code above can get all albums(custom + sync + import)
2. or the nest enume items means what i want

PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumSyncedAlbum can get album which come from itunes sync.